# Updating a rules file so it won't be overwritten on update

Tags: filesystem, bluetooth, system

Due to current issues with Logitech Bluetooth devices, I need to update the `/lib/udev/rules.d/70-hid2hci.rules` file.

A few weeks ago, an update overwrote this file (with an attempted fix that didn't, for many, work), and it took a while for me to realise why my mouse and keyboard stopped working again.

I have memories of being able to store an overriding rules file to a usr directory that will be checked before the lib file, but can't remember the specifics.

Could someone please jog my memory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should put udev rules files in `/etc/udev/rules.d`; they won't get overwritten on package upgrades.

Answer (score 2):

The answer lies not too far away :-)

In the `/lib/udev/rules.d` directory is a file named `README` which helps you deal with rules files.

Basically and this could apply to your case, you should create a new file called `71-hid2hci.rules`. You should save this file in `/etc/udev/rules.d` (take care it's under `/etc` and not `/lib`). As this file starts with a number higher than the one you're trying to alter, it will override it.

I hope this will help you solve your problem.

Comment: If you read that README file, it will tell you that you should put your overrides in `/etc/udev/rules.d`, not "in the same directory". :-)

Comment: Thanks Chris. @Huygens +1 for the README pointer (though the wiki means you won't get it, sorry)

Comment: Good eyes Chris :) I really was wondering for awhile at your comment before I could understand it! Perhaps I should get some sleep. I'm going to update the answer so it is accurate.