# Switching to Nvidia driver switched my system to X11. Now I'm back to using Nouveau but can't seem to switch back to Wayland? [Ubuntu 22.04]

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, 22.04, wayland

I was using 22.04 LTS out of the box with Nouveau and Wayland. It was working really well (I could even choose to run programs with the integrated GPU or the discrete GPU!), but I had an issue I thought was related to the graphics driver (TLDR: it wasn't).

As part of my troubleshooting I switched to the Nvidia driver. I went to *Settings -> About -> Software Updates -> Additional Drivers*. From there I checked the box for
`NVIDIA driver (open kernel) metapackage from nvidia-driver-530-open (proprietary, tested)`. After restarting and logging in, I noticed my system had switched to X11.

However, now I am no longer using the Nvidia driver. I went back into the *Additional Drivers* tab and checked the box for Nouveau, but my system is still using X11. In fact, the only Nouveau option now listed there is Nouveau with X.Org (see screenshot below).

[image: settings screenshot]

I don't have a gear icon at the login screen that lets me choose, as some answers have suggested. Likewise, editing `/etc/gdm3/custom.conf` and setting `WaylandEnable=true` does nothing. So right now it seems I'm stuck with X11 and no longer have the graphics card switcher options I had out of the box. It's pretty frustrating that I can't seem to just revert back to the prior settings...

How can I switch back to Wayland?

Comment: The gear only appears when the password field is being displayed (after user selection).  Choices vary, depending upon hardware but when "Wayland" is not visible, and the non "ubuntu" choice is xorg, ubuntu is the default with Wayland. check with ps ax |grep wayland to see if you are running wayland.

Comment: @ubfan1 I've checked and there's no gear icon even when I've selected a user and the password field is displayed. Likewise, I confirmed Wayland is not running by checking *Settings->About*, and under *Windowing System* it says "X11". Similarly, ```loginctl show-session $SESSIONID -p Type``` returns ```Type=x11```

Comment: You mean WaylandEnable in youur config file?  What Nvida hardware do you use?  Did you try an Nvidia driver not ending in "-open" (sometimes a script gets confused looking for a version number)?

Comment: Whoops, yes I meant WaylandEnable, that's merely a typo in my question, not the .conf file itself. For some reason at the moment lshw, lspci, etc. are detecting the Nvidia GPU but merely reporting the model as "NVIDIA Corporation". And I only tried the one Nvidia driver, though I don't think that's important since I'm now back to Nouveau which was my original setup.

Answer (score 0):

These two posts on ubuntu forums show to review the /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/61-gdm.rules.

https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2486867&p=14143185#post14143185

https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2486867&p=14143243#post14143243

I was able to boot back into wayland after blacklisting nouveau driver, installing my nvidia card drivers (AMD Card already installed, select no to installing OpenGL or Graphics libararies when prompted),renaming the file /usr/lib/udev/61-gdm.rules to /usr/lib/udev/61-gdm.rules.old and then touch to create a new empty file /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/61-gdm.rules hoping that any subsequent updates do not replace the file. **Unfortunately it appears recent graphics updates in ubuntu 22.04.3 break something with the udev rules file but am not perfectly sure. It ran over a year like this now when I run some updates it goes back to starting in x11 and I think it is because the udev rule, no way to know for sure, I just restored with timeshift. Wish me luck with placing my rules with priority and hope it works when I update next. This post shows to ensure the rule takes priority, it needs to be placed in /etc/udev/rules.d and have a higher number it starts with than the one in usr/lib/udev/.

https://askubuntu.com/a/6158/1652771

My use case is Nvidia K80 running compute only and does not process any graphics outputs and does not need an x-thread. It works great with stable diffusion (have to install specific versions of pytorch and cuda, but is easy), and works within both gimp, and blender but requires some help for some things. In order to make this work, required to have a separate AMD GPU as the primary gpu, and do when prompted upon installing the nvidia driver to choose if you would like to install OpenGL or EGL as a current other version is already installed, SELECT NO. You have to have your AMD Card all setup and working before installing the NVIDIA card, and should not be using the AMD proprietary drivers (not sure which it is OpenGL, or EGL has been a while.)

Since I had to look back at this today, and had a hard time finding what I was looking for, this unanswered question (Oddly the first result on google) is where I am placing the information I need to get back to, that and keeping it in a file somewhere with my other notes on pytorch versions.

Comment: I'm glad you commented! I had completely forgotten I asked this. I never actually figured out how to get back to Wayland, but it ended up not being an issue in my case. I thought the Nvidia driver was causing all my issues, but it was actually because at some point during troubleshooting I had added "nomodeset" to the grub parameters list. After removing that a lot of the graphics problems I experienced went away. As a result I ended up just sticking with the Nvidia driver and X11